# referenced memory could not be read in java

Tags: java, database, runtime-error

I am trying to run an installed database driven java application on windows 7 ultimate,but it gives me this error:

> "The instruction at 0x000d8663 referenced memory at 0x0403c2f0.The
>   memory could not be read.  Click OK to terminate the program."

I have checked stackoverflow for similar questions but they didn't have clear answers and some didn't have answers at all.I have also searched via google but I could not come up with an explanation of the error.I would like to know what's causing the error or an explanation of the error and maybe a way to fix it.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows problem with RAM addresses. What program are you trying to run and where did you get it? If downloaded, try another download source, it could be corrupted.

Comment: Most likely you have a corrupted program at the native code level or you have an incompatible DLL. Try updating the version of windows and Java and try again.

Comment: I wrote the program myself,it is a simple program that is designed to store data and retrieve it at realtime for the user.I have installed it on a computer but this other computer gives me the error when trying to run it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey,Thanks.The version of java is updated,it works fine on another computer.

Comment: Your Java software cannot produce this error on a correctly installed system.  The problem is you are using an incompatible or corrupt DLL.

Comment: Thanks,so please how can I fix that?